# Trailblazer Operation undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, trailblazer

I have a simple Trailblazer Operation as follow:

```
class User::Delete < Trailblazer::Operation
  extend Contract::DSL

  contract 'params' do
    property :token

    validates :token, presence: true
  end

  step    Contract::Validate(name: 'params'), before: 'operation.new'
  success :kill_zombie

  def kill_zombie(options, params:, **)
    options['killed'] = true
  end

end
```

When I run the operation under the rails console, that's the output:

```
irb(main):003:0> User::Delete.()
NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):3
```

If I remove the Contract line:

```
class User::Delete < Trailblazer::Operation
  extend Contract::DSL

  contract 'params' do
    property :token

    validates :token, presence: true
  end

  success :kill_zombie

  def kill_zombie(options, params:, **)
    options['killed'] = true
  end

end
```

It works as expected:

```
irb(main):005:0> User::Delete.()
=> <Result:true <Skill {"killed"=>true} {"params"=>{}} {"pipetree"=>[>operation.new,>kill_zombie], "contract.params.class"=>#<Class:0x0000000003e54e50>}> >
irb(main):006:0>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `Contract::Build` before `Contract::Validate` when using a Reform contract. With a `Dry` schema, the build step isn't needed.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet code (even if it's redundant from the documentation) ?

Answer (score 1):

I would dig deep in the documentation http://trailblazer.to/gems/operation/2.0/contract.html

The message means that [you are trying to call a method on a `nil` object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250629/ruby-on-rails-undefined-method-call-for-nilnilclass#3250713).

The Object is `User::Delete` and the method is `.()`

```
User::Delete.()
```

`User::Delete` could be undefined because it is not passing your validation?

```
step    Contract::Validate(name: 'params'), before: 'operation.new'
```

Just posting to give you some input, I don't have a solution. I would inspect `User::Delete` before calling the method.

`User::Delete` will be `nil` and you need to change the validation or make sure that object is correctly instantiated.

Comment: Just dug in the documentation, I feel like I have to use Dry::Validation for linear validations

Comment: @JeremieGes yes something like `(Dry::Validation.Schema do
    required(:id).filled
  end)` from http://trailblazer.to/gems/operation/2.0/contract.html#dry-schema